# How do I post an example of a CSV to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, posting

I'm trying to ask a question about combining CSV files in Python, and since I'm new to this site I can't post images of it. How do I create a column by row example like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978092/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-python-pandas) has done?

Comment: Tabs between columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have shown uses a code block - that is, four spaces at the start of each line. From there, you can take advantage of the monospace font in the textarea to lay things out how you want, just make sure to double-check in the preview before posting!

Answer (score 3):

**You need to block your words and press ctrl-K** (or choose toolbar {})
, it mean your word will be in code format. Just try it

Answer (score 2):

You could use the HTML option. Use the pre-tag and then paste your CSV between the tags.